# how to copy a folder into another folder

Tags: xubuntu

I have folder in this path :

```
/home/practice/app/asset
```

I want to copy that folder into

```
/var/www/html
```

Comment: Do you have write permission on the destination folder? You may have to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo cp -Rpf /home/practice/app/asset /var/www/html/
```